# Join videos with split screen

Tags: linux, video, command-line, ffmpeg

I am looking for a command to join two video files, however I want the videos joined split-screen, frame by frame, instead of one after another.

Any ideas? Seems this is not possible with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With a recent version of ffmpeg (assuming both videos are the same resolution):

```bsh
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 \
 -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int]; \
     [int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]" \
-map "[vid]" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 \
output.mp4
```

This essentially doubles the size of input1.mp4 by [padding](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) the right side with black the same size as the original video, and then places input2.mp4 over the top of that black area with the [overlay](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) filter.

If one of your videos has an audio track that you need to add to the output, add the option `-map 0:a` for the first file's audio, or `-map 1:a` for the second file's audio.

If you have two audio tracks that you would like to mix, use the `amix` filter:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 \
 -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int]; \
     [int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]; \
     [0:a][1:a]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest[aud]" \
-map "[vid]" \
-map "[aud]" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 \
-c:a aac -b:a 192k \
output.mp4
```

Comment: I'm getting `Unrecognized option 'crf'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`. If I remove `cr` then `unrecognized option 'preset'`

Comment: You might get the following error if your videos have an odd number of pixels on a given size:

    `[Parsed_pad_0 @ 0x1e6e1c0] Input area 0:0:445:369 not within the padded area 0:0:890:368 or zero-sized`

Simply adding 1 to the width and height of the output gets rid of this problem:

   `ffmpeg -i left.avi -i right.avi -filter_complex \
    '[0:v]pad=iw*2+1:ih+1[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]' \
    -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output.avi`

Comment: I get [AVFilterGraph @ 0000025e2fb2b480] No such filter: '[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]'
Error initializing complex filters.

Comment: Let's say I want to do this with three videos, or four. What would I need to change to do so?

Answer (score -4):

this can be done with the SOC version of libavfilter and some ingenuity