# vlc add extra media file to video

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I want to merge two video files to a single video file. (No concating)

Via the vlc GUI, I can achieve this:
vlc menu bar -> Media -> Convert/Save -> Show more options -> Play another media synchronously.

How to do this via the CLI?

I am not searching for this solution https://superuser.com/a/537482 because I want two separated video streams / windows.

Answer (score 2):

VLC GUI actually shows you the CLI equivalent!

When you check "Play another media synchronously" and choose the media file, the field "Options" above gets updated to include `:input-slave=file:///Path/To/Media/file.ext` etc.

The same command line option is also documented in [VLC command-line help](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) and `vlc -H`:

> ```
>   --input-slave=<string>     Input slave (experimental)
>       This allows you to play from several inputs at the same time. This
>       feature is experimental, not all formats are supported. Use a '#'
>       separated list of inputs.
> ```