# ffmpeg: Unrecognized option 'crf'. Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm trying to merge two videos (like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/153160/join-videos-split-screen)) side by side.
The full log with command:

```
    ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]' -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output.mp4
ffmpeg version N-90232-g0645698ecc Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2)
  configuration: --disable-x86asm
  libavutil      56.  8.100 / 56.  8.100
  libavcodec     58. 13.102 / 58. 13.102
  libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavfilter     7. 12.100 /  7. 12.100
  libswscale      5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
Unrecognized option 'crf'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

But getting message mentioned in the title.
I have ffmpeg version N-90232-g0645698ecc from Ubuntu 17.10 repos.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Mulvya done, take a look, please.

Comment: You need a ffmpeg binary with libx264 included. Get it from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: @Mulvya thanks, also I would appreciate if someone knows how to make it work with usual build.

Comment: @RS Your version `N-90232-g0645698ecc` is not from the repo. It looks like a compiled version. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu for compile guide, or just use the actual ffmpeg package from the repo.

Comment: @Gyan 's reference/binary works for redhat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` is not from the Ubuntu 17.10 repo and looks like it was compiled on your machine. It lacks `--enable-gpl --enable-libx264` which is required to use `-c:v libx264`. Unrelated, but it has `--disable-x86asm` which is never recommended as it will result in slowness.

You have several options to fix this:

- Use the *ffmpeg* package from the repo: `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`
- [Download a recent compiled `ffmpeg` binary](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and put it in `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`.
- Follow the [Ubuntu guide on the FFmpeg Wiki to compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: Can you tell me how to use the above command in Android using bravobit android dependencies ?

Comment: @VivekMishra I don't know anything about bravobit android dependencies. I recommend asking a new question.

Answer (score 3):

In my case was anaconda3 which my system was calling ( and installling, removing, etc didn't fix my problem), you could find out if it is your case with:

```
whereis ffmpeg
```

After that I saw all the possible path, the system was calling `conda` version instead of `system` version. To be sure you have a compatible version with `--crf` install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

then for calling with it, you should use the path from the system or modify your PATH variables (this is modify `~/.profile` or `~/.bash` or [more options and how it works here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227989/complete-view-of-where-the-path-variable-is-set-in-bash)). I didn't do that because everything works with ffmpeg conda version except the `--crf` argument.

How to use the compatible version with `--crf`

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 output.mp4
```

Where  `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` is a one of the results of `whereis ffmpeg`